# Displaying the results of a multi-table query

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am trying to display the results of the following:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
user_name: "tobagoborn",
type: 'cartodb',
sublayers: [{
    sql: "(SELECT L.the_geom_webmercator, L.landing_sites, F.first_name, F.last_name,C.number_of_species, C.cartodb_id FROM catch C, lsites L, fishermen F WHERE C.have_catch = 1 AND C.site_code = L.site_code AND C.fisherman_id = F.fisherman_id;}", // AND C.catch_date > now()::date";
    cartocss: '#catch {marker-fill: #FF0000;}',
    interactivity: 'landing_sites,first_name,last_name,number_of_species',
    }]
})
.addTo(map)
.on('done', function(layer) {
    var sublayer0 = layer.getSubLayer(0);
    cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, sublayer0, 
       ['landing_sites','first_name','last_name','number_of_species'],
       {infowindowTemplate: $('#infowindow_template').html()});
})
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
   //log the error
});
```

I understand how to display the results of a single table query.  but need some assistance with doing the same with the SQL statement above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is invalid. (The braces at beginning and end of statement).

```
"(SELECT L.the_geom_webmercator, L.landing_sites, F.first_name, F.last_name,C.number_of_species, C.cartodb_id FROM catch C, lsites L, fishermen F WHERE C.have_catch = 1 AND C.site_code = L.site_code AND C.fisherman_id = F.fisherman_id;}"
```

Should be

```
"SELECT L.the_geom_webmercator, L.landing_sites, F.first_name, F.last_name,C.number_of_species, C.cartodb_id FROM catch C, lsites L, fishermen F WHERE C.have_catch = 1 AND C.site_code = L.site_code AND C.fisherman_id = F.fisherman_id"
```

Comment: Thanks Jags!! It was the extra curly brace inside of the quotes of the SQL statement.  Just a note... I did not get an error msg in my console

Comment: @ChrisJ Yeah the error messages from layer creation calls can be vague AND/OR absent, so it's best to test things in the CartoDB Editor first.